# Allow more objects on a page in Visio 2016

Tags: microsoft-visio

I've got about six classes drawn on a page in Visio and would likt to add some more but there is no space.

Years ago I did a resize of the objects but can't seem te find the option.

Anyone?

[image]

Comment: Have you clicked the objects and re sized on the corner? or is that not possible in 2016? using click and clicking one of the circles while holding shift should keep the quality.

Comment: I can resize the objects but the text in the object remain the same size. And I'm looking for a global solution and not resize each and every object.

Comment: Make the page/drawing area larger? You can scale down to print ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Changed the print zoom did work

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If yes I will add an answer.

Comment: it did add your answer and I'll mark it